# Codeigniter Calling Controller with data from a form issue

Tags: php, codeigniter, controller

Trying to call the projects controller and the editproject function and pass an id number. Can anyone tell me why the second line doesn't work? When I echo the value in the first line, it does give me the correct integer as a string

```
<?php echo $list[0]->id; ?>

<?php echo form_open('projects/editproject/',$list[0]->id ) ;?>
```

The error I keep getting is "Missing argument 1 for Projects::editproject()" My editproject function is function editproject($id).

I did try:

```
<?php echo $list[0]->id; ?>
<?php $pdata = (int)$list[0]->id; ?>
<?php echo form_open('projects/editproject/',$pdata ) ;?>
```

Thinking the call to the controller needed a variable for the data. Same error message as above. THanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you mean to do this instead ?

```
<?php echo form_open('projects/editproject/'.$list[0]->id ) ;?>
```

The second argument of form_open() accepts an associative array of attributes, hence, you're mistakenly passing in the id into the second argument when it needs to be concatenated with the url instead.

Comment: Thought I had tried this as one of my many options, but punched it in and it worked fine. Too many hours at the keyboard I guess. Thank you.

Comment: Not a problem, please mark it as answered when you get the chance, the green check mark on the left under the 0, thanks!

Comment: I will. It is making me wait 10 minutes before I accept. Is that typical?